# ReactJS unit test with Mocha, enzyme and chai-enzyme simulate('click') not working

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, enzyme, chai, sinon

I have attached both component and test file. In the test file second case is failing. simulate('click') is not working and it is always returning false. I am unable to figure out why it isn't simulate click is not working. Can anyone help me with this? I am using Mocha with enzyme and for mocking an event i am using sinon. Mocha is mandatory to use.

```
Component
---------

import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Modal, Search, TextArea, TextInput } from "carbon-components-react";

function RulesComponent(props) {
    const [ filteredList, setFilteredList ] = useState([]);
    const [ showEditModal, setShowEditModal ] = useState(false);
    const [ showDeleteModal, setShowDeleteModal ] = useState(false);
    const [ textareaReadonly, setTextareaReadonly ] = useState(true);
    const [ showNewRuleModal, setShowNewRuleModal ] = useState(false);
    const [ fileNameError, setFileNameError] = useState(false);
    const textAreaEl = useRef(null)

    const { ruleFilesList, newRuleBtnClick, newRuleName, onNewRuleNameChange, deleteRuleBtnClick, onRuleChange, ruleChange, rulesPath, ruleDescription, onRuleDescriptionChange, setSelected, refresh, selectedRule } = props;

    const handleFilter = (event) => {
        let newList = ruleFilesList.filter((item) => item.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1 )
        setFilteredList(newList);
    }

    const handleEditRule = () => {
        setShowEditModal(true)
    }

    const handleDeleteRule = () => {
        setShowDeleteModal(true)
    }

    const handleNewRule = () => {
        setShowNewRuleModal(true)
    }

    const handleSubmitEditRule = () => {
        if(ruleChange) {
            setTextareaReadonly(false)
      } else {
        }
        setShowEditModal(false)
    }

    const handleNewRuleFileSubmit = () => {
        const checkExtension = newRuleName.toLowerCase().split('.');
        console.log(newRuleName)
        if(newRuleName && checkExtension[1] === 'txt') {
            newRuleBtnClick()
            setShowNewRuleModal(false)
        } else {
            setFileNameError(true)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if(ruleFilesList) {
            setFilteredList(ruleFilesList)
        }
    }, [ruleFilesList])

    useEffect(() => {
        if(!textareaReadonly) {
            textAreaEl.current.focus();
        }
    }, [textareaReadonly])

    return (
        <div className="rules-content">
            <div className="bx--row">
                <div className="bx--col-xs-2 bx--col-sm-2 bx--col-md-2 bx--col-lg-2">
                    <Button className="rules-btn" size="small" id="new-rule" onClick={handleNewRule} data-test="new-rule">New</Button>
                </div>
                <div className="bx--col-xs-2 bx--col-sm-2 bx--col-md-2 bx--col-lg-2">
                    <Button className="rules-btn" size="small" onClick={handleEditRule}>Edit</Button>
                </div>
                <div className="bx--col-xs-2 bx--col-sm-2 bx--col-md-2 bx--col-lg-2">
                    <Button className="rules-btn" size="small" onClick={handleDeleteRule}>Delete</Button>
                </div>
                <div className="bx--col-xs-6 bx--col-sm-6 bx--col-md-6 bx--col-lg-6 selected-rule-box">
                    <div className="selected-rule-text">
                        { !localStorage.getItem('Selected_Rule') ? selectedRule : localStorage.getItem('Selected_Rule') }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="search-input">
                <Search id="search" labelText="" placeHolderText="Search" size="lg" onChange={handleFilter}/>
            </div>
            <div className="rules-list">
                {
                    filteredList && filteredList.map((filename) => {
                        return <p 
                                className={`rules-list-item ${ruleChange === filename ? 'selected-rule' : ''}`} 
                                key={filename} 
                                onClick={() => {
                                    onRuleChange(filename)
                                    setTextareaReadonly(true)
                                }}
                            >
                                {filename}
                            </p>
                    })
                }
            </div>
            <TextInput
                className="rules-path-input"
                id="rulespath"
                name="rulespath"
                value={rulesPath}
                labelText=""
                placeholder="Rules Path"
                type="text"
                readOnly
            />
            <TextArea
                className="rules-description"
                ref={textAreaEl}
                id="rulesdescription"
                name="rulesdescription" 
                value={ruleDescription}
                onChange={onRuleDescriptionChange}
                labelText=""
                placeholder=""
                type="text"
                rows={12}
                readOnly={textareaReadonly}
            />
            <div className="bx--row rule-footer">
                <div className="bx--col-xs-7 bx--col-sm-7 bx--col-md-7 bx--col-lg-7">
                    <div className="rule-footer-text">Select a rules file. Click on 'set selected' button to use the rules file for processing.</div>
                </div>
                <div className="bx--col-xs-3 bx--col-sm-3 bx--col-md-3 bx--col-lg-3">
                    <Button className="rules-btn" size="small" onClick={setSelected}>Set selected</Button>
                </div>
                <div className="bx--col-xs-2 bx--col-sm-2 bx--col-md-2 bx--col-lg-2">
                    <Button className="rules-btn" size="small" onClick={refresh}>Refresh</Button>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            {/* --------Show new rule modal-------- */}
            <Modal
                hasForm
                className="new-rule-modal"
                iconDescription="Close"
                open={showNewRuleModal}
                primaryButtonText="Save"
                secondaryButtonText="Cancel"
                size="sm"
                onRequestClose={() => setShowNewRuleModal(false)}
                onRequestSubmit={handleNewRuleFileSubmit}
                modalLabel="New Rule"
                selectorPrimaryFocus="#rule-name"
            >
                <TextInput 
                    id="rule-name" 
                    name="rulename" 
                    value={newRuleName} 
                    onChange={(event) => (onNewRuleNameChange(event), setFileNameError(false))}
                    labelText=""
                    placeholder="Enter File Name"
                    invalidText="Please enter the file name with .txt extension"
                    helperText="Enter the file with .txt extension"
                    invalid={fileNameError}
                />
            </Modal>
            
            {/* -------Show edit modal------- */}
            <Modal
                className="edit-modal"
                iconDescription="Close"
                open={showEditModal}
                primaryButtonText="Ok"
                secondaryButtonText="Cancel"
                size="sm"
                onRequestSubmit={handleSubmitEditRule}
                onRequestClose={() => setShowEditModal(false)}
            >
                {
                    ruleChange ? `Do you want to edit ${ruleChange}?` : 'Please select a rule from the list box to edit.'
                }
            </Modal>

            {/* --------Show delete modal-------- */}
            <Modal
                className="delete-modal"
                iconDescription="Close"
                open={showDeleteModal}
                primaryButtonText="Ok"
                secondaryButtonText="Cancel"
                size="sm"
                onRequestSubmit={() => ruleChange ? (deleteRuleBtnClick(ruleChange), setShowDeleteModal(false)) : setShowDeleteModal(false)}
                onRequestClose={() => setShowDeleteModal(false)}
            >
                {
                     ruleChange ? `Do you want to delete ${ruleChange}?` : 'Please select a rule from the list box to delete.'
                }
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
}

export default RulesComponent

Rules.test.js
-------------

import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import chai, { expect } from 'chai';
import chaiEnzyme from 'chai-enzyme';
import { spy } from 'sinon';
import RulesComponent from '../components/Rules';


describe('Rules component testing', () => {
    let handleClick = spy();
    const props = {
        handleNewRule: handleClick
    }
    let wrapper = shallow(<RulesComponent {...props}/>)
    let input;

    beforeEach(() => {
        input = "";
    })

    afterEach(() => {
       
    })
    
    it('Should contain a button with text \"New\" ', () => {
        input = wrapper.find("[data-test='new-rule']");
        // console.log(input.debug())
        expect(input).to.exist;
        expect(input).to.contain.text('New');
    })

    it('Should fire onClick event on \"New\" button click', () => {
        input = wrapper.find("[data-test='new-rule']").at(0).dive().find("[data-test='new-rule']");
        input.simulate('click');
        console.log(input.debug())
        expect(handleClick.calledOnce).to.be.true // failed (returning false)
    })

    chai.use(chaiEnzyme());
})
```